# near-api-js, view contract method call gives: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures

Tags: javascript, nearprotocol

Whenever I am calling my contract `view` method using `near-cli`, it is working fine, the terminal outputs the result correctly in JSON format.

But when I call the same method using `near-api-js` method in my angular project, it gives an error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.
```

Output from `near-cli` for reference and also the expected output when I call the same method via `near-api-js`:

```json
{
  files: [
    {
      owner: 'some string',
      key: 'some string',
      cid: 'some string'
    }
  ],
  length: 1
}
```

What may be the cause of this and what's the solution?

Comment: It might be a syntax issue. what does your `near-cli` call look like vs `near-api-js`?

Comment: Yeah, it was a syntactical error, I was passing the wrong parameter to the function call. It was expecting something else

Comment: would you mind posting your solution and marking this as answered?

Comment: I had to pass a different argument... ;D

Answer (score 2):

Circular reference example:

```
var circularReference = {otherData: 123};
circularReference.myself = circularReference;
JSON.stringify(circularReference);
```

Explanation: `circularReference` refers to itself via `cirularReference.myself`.

[Mozilla's website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value) has a nice example of how the circular reference can be found and removed:

```
const getCircularReplacer = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};

JSON.stringify(circularReference, getCircularReplacer());
// {"otherData":123}
```

Instead of removing the circular reference, you can modify it.

However, this is symptomatic treatment. The very best would be to find out why the circular reference appeared in the first place and if that's caused by a bug, then fix it.

Comment: It was a bug, I figured it out, I was calling the function wrong... Thanks though!